# Android Studio 2.2.2 Unable to drag and drop

Tags: android, android-studio, drag-and-drop, android-studio-2.2

I am unable to drag and drop from the palette in design view. I have searched multiple threads and found that the alt key must be pressed. However i have tried that, and even unchecked that option (settings>appearances) and still no success. When i try to drag something, it appears on the device screen for a split second and then disappears.

Thanks.

Comment: Solved. Updated JDK, however had to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Try it again while editor language is default not locale.

Comment: Sorry to be a noob, but how would i do that?